# ListView.builder is not working in side a column

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

ListView.builder is working fine in side a center(). but when i change    center to a column ListView.builder is not scrolling.

```
return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Center(
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                    value: names
                        .contains(snapshot.data[index].data["Name"]),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["Name"]),
                    onChanged: (bool selected) {
                      //markMember(snapshot.data[index].data["Name"]);
                      _onCategorySelected(
                          selected,       snapshot.data[index].data["Name"],snapshot.data[index].data["IndexNo"]);
                    }),
              );

            }),
          ],

        );
```

i want to add another FloatingActionButton under the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `floatingActionButton` parameter of `Scaffold` to use `FloatingActionButton`, So you don't need to put `ListView` inside a `Column` for that.

**Example**

```
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _openFilePicker,
    child: Icon(Icons.attach_file),
  ),
  body: // Your ListView goes here.
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I did it this way. i'm new to flutter.

Comment: You're welcome friend. Same here, I'm a newbie as well. :D

Answer (score 0):

if you want to enable scrolling in `listview` while it is inside `column` widget then wrap your `ListView.builder` widget with `Expanded` widget.

```
return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
         Expanded(
           child:  ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Center(
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                    value: names
                        .contains(snapshot.data[index].data["Name"]),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["Name"]),
                    onChanged: (bool selected) {
                      //markMember(snapshot.data[index].data["Name"]);
                      _onCategorySelected(
                          selected,
snapshot.data[index].data["Name"],snapshot.data[index].data["IndexNo"]);
                    }),
              );

            })),
          ],

        );
```